# C: Standard input and file input, how to input a string and show new lines in the file

Tags: c, input, file-io, newline

I probably have a basic problem with standard input and file input.
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("../testFile.txt", "w+");
    printf("PLEASE ENTER:\n");

    char str[9999];
    scanf("%s", str);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",str);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

When I try to enter `123\r\n345\r\n567`, it shows `123\r\n345\r\n567` in testFile.txt. Obviously `\r\n` is not regarded as newline characters. I want it shows,

```
123
345
567
```

or something like it which contains many lines. Thanks.

Comment: Then you need to parse the string and replace the substring `"\r\n"` with a proper newline character.

Comment: `scanf("%s", str);` does not read a _line_.  Use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do it in a loop and then write each number to the file separately.
Assuming you don't know how many numbers you will insert in advance ask the user first, save it in a int variable and run the loop on it